# For JSON Schemas, is it better to use "allOf" for referenced definitions?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In a JSON schema, when a property references another defined schema, to preserve the type of the referenced definitionis it better to wrap the referenced definition in an "allOf" and indicate the property type in that definition outside the referenced definition? Or is it better to indicate the property type inside of the referenced definition and not use "allOf"?

For example, in the first schema below, the property references for mainObject and objectA are both wrapped in "allOf" and and have "type": "object" within the mainObject and objectA properties. Whereas in Schema Version 2, the "mainObject" and "objectAInfo" definitions indicate the "type" of "object".

From what I have seen in testing, both of these achieve the same validations goals, so I am wondering if there is particular reason to use Schema Version 1 over Schema Version 2?

Schema Version 1:

```
{
  "info": {
    "title": "mainObject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "baseUri": "",
    "description": "An example object schema"
  },
  "properties": {
    "mainObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/mainObject"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [],
  "definitions": {
    "mainObject": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "description": "The financials entity root.",
      "required": [],
      "properties": {
        "objectA": {
          "type": "object",
          "description": "Information on the liability accrued by the taxpayer",
          "allOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/objectAInfo"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "objectAInfo": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [],
      "properties": {
        "total1": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "Overall liability accrued during the tax period. This number does not go down as the taxpayer pays off their liability. That is reflected in the periodBalance."
        },
        "total2": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "Overall liability accrued during the tax period. This number does not go down as the taxpayer pays off their liability. That is reflected in the periodBalance."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "lang": "zxx",
  "$id": "http://example.com/"
}
```

Schema Version 2:

```
{
  "info": {
    "title": "mainObject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "baseUri": "",
    "description": "An example object schema"
  },
  "properties": {
    "mainObject": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/mainObject"
    }
  },
  "required": [],
  "definitions": {
    "mainObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "description": "The financials entity root.",
      "required": [],
      "properties": {
        "objectA": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/objectAInfo"
        }
      }
    },
    "objectAInfo": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [],
      "properties": {
        "total1": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "Overall liability accrued during the tax period. This number does not go down as the taxpayer pays off their liability. That is reflected in the periodBalance."
        },
        "total2": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "Overall liability accrued during the tax period. This number does not go down as the taxpayer pays off their liability. That is reflected in the periodBalance."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "lang": "zxx",
  "$id": "http://example.com/"
}
```

Example doc to validate:

```
{
  "mainObject": {
    "objectA": {
      "total1": 0,
      "total2": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on three things:

1. Which draft are you using?  Draft 7 and earlier *require* the `$ref` to be by itself, which means if you have other constraints (for example, the `type` in your Schema 1), they would be ignored.  However, in draft 2019-09 and later, `$ref` *can* have sibling keywords (`type` would also be validated).
2. Multiple references.  If you have multiple references, you MUST put them in separate subschemas within an `allOf`.  Otherwise you'd have duplicate `$ref` keys.
3. Readability.  Even for modern schemas, some people still prefer to have the reference by itself simply to help them isolate different requirement sets.  This is personal opinion.

Short answer: for modern schema implementations, it's up to you.  Just be sure you declare which version your using with `$schema`.